# Can't remove :hidden_field from input in ActiveAdmin

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, input, activeadmin, formtastic

I am putting in the input of the ActiveAdmin Formtastic form an array of checkboxes (as: `:checkboxes`) to later use to populate a ManyToMany intermediary table that is not part of the model itself being saved on the form. But when I try to use the checkboxes, it creates automatically a hidden blank checkbox, so I can't require it to not be empty because it never is. Does anyone know of any solution? I tried `hidden_fields: false` and `required: true` but it seems to ignore both.

The code:

```
input :object_ids, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Object.all, input_html: {hidden_fields: false, required: true, allow_blank: false, hint: 'Please enter an object'}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty on my ActiveAdmin and Formastic but
I think that you could try something like below

```
input :object_ids, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Object.all, include_hidden: false, include_blank: false, hint: 'Please enter an object', input_html: {required: true}
```